# require,js different number of arguments

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am new to require.js and I see old code like this

```
define(["underscore", "require", "backbone"], function (_, require) {
// some code which returns SOME_NAMESPACE
});
```

Here I  see 3 parameters in define but only 2 in function . What's the use of this ?

Edit : This seems to somehow return a namespace which is extended in other classes a backbone model . so it seems its somehow making a backbone base class ?  kindly suggest .

Comment: Backbone must have some piece of code that runs when imported, like an internal setup or some other side effect, but the caller of define doesn't actually need the exported module.

Comment: Maybe the backbone is defining itself via global variable, thus it is needed to require it, but not inject into the function.